# How to give image path in lightning salesforce?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I am giving my image path. I am following [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.202.0.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_resource_value_provider.htm).

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="{!$Resource.Kola + '/assets/Koala/Koala.JPEG'}"  />
```

here Kola---->My static resource foldername
  Koala->>>>>My foldername
Koala.jpege----My image name

The output looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are correctly referring the image(`Koala.JPEG`) which resides inside `Koala`(folder) which is inturn is inside `assests`(folder), then i think below statement might me the reason for the image loading issue:

> Resource isn’t available until the Lightning Component framework is
>   loaded on the client. Some very simple components that are composed of
>   only markup can be rendered server-side, where $Resource isn’t
>   available. To avoid this, when you create a new app, stub out a
>   client-side controller to force components to be rendered on the
>   client.

As mentioned above, if your component contains only markups which uses `$Resource`, then you need to create `controller` file for the component to force components to be rendered on the client.

**test.cmp**:(this won't work if there is no controller)

```
<aura:component >
 <img src="{!$Resource.SLDS100 + '/assets/images/avatar1.jpg'}" width="100" height="100"/>
</aura:component>
```

If you go head and create a controller for the above component, then image would render properly

**testController.js**(dummy controller)

```
({
    myAction : function(component, event, helper) {

    }
})
```